# Merge multiple cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, merge, cell

My cell array `S <1x4cell>` contains 4 cell arrays (`<108x1cell>`,`<106x1cell>`,`<111x1cell>`,`<115x1cell>`), each of which contains a list of roughly a hundred file paths.

I want to merge them in order to get one single cell with all my paths.
Is there a single function to do that?

Comment: See: [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider accepting the answer (green check mark on the left), if it helped you. This way you indicate the system that your problem is solved! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Concatenate your cell arrays and use [**`unique`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
%// example data
A ={'a';
     'b';
     'c';
     'd'};
B = {'a';
     'e';
     'f'};
C = {'g';
     'a';
     'c'};

%// merge cells
merged = [A(:); B(:); C(:)]
%// or
merged = cat(1, A(:), B(:), C(:))

%// remove duplicates
filtered = unique(merged)
```

---

or assumiming you already have the cell array `S = merged`, do the following:

```
S = { A, B, C }

%// remove duplicates
filtered = unique(cat(1,S{:}))
```

Comment: OK, here is an example of my data: A={{'my/file/path1';'my/file/path/2'};{'another/file/path3';'another/file/path/4'}}

Comment: @JérômeRedouté Glad I could help and welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider accepting the answer (green check mark on the left) to indicate the system that the problem is solved. Thank you!